# discover a certain part of a page with selenium

Tags: xpath, selenium

I have a webpage looks something like this:

```
<html>
...
<div id="menu">
...
  <ul id="listOfItems">
  <!--- repeated block start -->
    <li id="item" class="itemClass">
    ...
    <span class="spanClass"><span class="title">title</span></span>
    ...
    </li>
  <!-- repeated block end-->
    <li id="item" class="itemClass">
    ...
    <span class="spanClass"><span class="title">title something</span></span>
    ...
    </li>
    <li id="item" class="itemClass">
    ...
    <span class="spanClass"><span class="title">title other thing</span></span>
    ...
   </li>
 </ul>
 ...
 </div>
 ...
 </html>
```

I would like to know what is the xpath of the titles ("title", "title something", "title  other thing"). The point is that the order of the `<li>` elements are not specified. It could be different after every page loading. Is there any method how to discover a certain structure of the page with xpath? I have an notion about how to solve this issue, but before I'm going to write iterations with `C#` to discover the page I ask you.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: On the java driver api, there's a `driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div//span[contains(@class, 'title'))` that would work for this. Hopefully the C# API is similar.

Comment: And only 2 hours later do I notice that my braces and quotes don't close properly: `driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='menu']//span[contains(@class, 'title')]"))`. I prefer to use contains for css classes (though you should probably normalize the whitespace if you do) in case you add classes dynamically. I also try to select elements under something with a definitive id (either the menu div or the listOfItems ul) just to reduce bad matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does Selenium support XPath expressions like:

```
//span[@class='title']
```

If yes, than use the above XPath expression. It selects every `span` element in the XML document, whose `class` attribute has string value of `"title"`.

**I recommend to use a tool like [the XPath Visualizer](http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html)** to play with different XPath expressions and see the selected nodes highlighted in the source XML document.

Comment: It is not recommended to use @class='title' unless you are absolutely certain the element you're looking for will always have just a single class. Instead I recommend you use //span[contains(@class,'title')]. Also, to answer your question, yes Selenium does support XPath expressions like the one you posted :)

Comment: And if you have any input into the page production insist on the development convention that different element 'types' have unique identifiers.

Comment: @ohaal: Yes, I don't need to be reminded about what the value of a `class` attribute may be. My solution solves the concrete problem that the author poses here -- it intentionally doesn't generalize, so that to focus on the concrete problem and not to distract the OP with potential generalizations.

Comment: @Martin Spamer: I don't understand your comment and how it relates to the current question -- could you, please, elaborate?

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev's answer would work well.  The more-general (but uglier) version, which works no matter how many other classes the element has, is: `//span[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' title ')]`

Comment: @RossPatterson: Yes, and if the sample XML contained such `class` attributes, I would definitely recommend exactly such answer.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, id's should be unique, so your portrayed webpage would not work well when it comes to testing.

I did however test, and got some XPath locators to work for selecting specific titles (although I recommend you fix your webpage instead of actually using this):

```
//li[@id='item']/span/span
//li[@id='item'][1]/span/span
//li[@id='item'][3]/span/span
```

If you're after all three titles, you could try [Dimitre Novatchev's suggestion:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9331802/1210983)

```
//span[@class='title']
```

This should get all titles on the page.

I would like to say one thing however, if you're getting into Selenium, I recommend you [download](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/1.6.0/selenium-ide-1.6.0.xpi) the [Selenium IDE extension](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) for Firefox. It's a great tool for beginners. It helps you both to make your Selenium tests by recording your clicks on a website, and it also helps you auto-generate and test your XPath locators and other locators.

And again: I urge you to not make a website with duplicate id elements :-)